# Kivy/python. One callback function for several buttons

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I started to realize an internet radio with a raspberry pi and a touch screen. I have placed several buttons on screen and I want to realize one callback function for all buttons. Differs which button was pressed, by an if-else structure.

kv-file:

```
BoxLayout:
    Button:
        text: "PLAY"
        on_press: root.ctrl_buttons()
    Button:
        text: "STOP"
        on_press: root.ctrl_buttons()
```

python-file:

```
def ctrl_buttons(self):
    if "play pressed":
        subprocess.check_output("mpc play", shell=True)
     elif "stop pressed":
         subprocess.check_output("mpc stop", shell=True)
```

I have found no way, to call the callback function with an parameter, which I can differ within the if-else structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use another argument in your function?

```
def ctrl_buttons(self, button):
    if button=="PLAY":
        print "pressed play"
    elif button=="STOP":
        print "pressed stop"
```

and in kivy use `root.ctrl_buttons(self.text)`

Can't remember if it wants another argument or not just for passing button, but if yes, then this is more effective:

```
def ctrl_buttons(self, button):
    if button.text=="PLAY":
        print "pressed play"
    elif button.text=="STOP":
        print "pressed stop"
```

Comment: I tried so many different thinks and nothing works. I think it always was a bite to the right code. Thanks.

Comment: I know the feeling. Like you know you're almost there, only a little change is needed.